# Problema com versões do IONIC

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, mobile, ionic3

Atualmente o **Ionic** está na versão 4, porém prefiro o **Ionic 3** principalmente para programar os temas do meu aplicativo.

Então, fiz o **downgrade** para versão **Ionic 3.1.0**. Mas, me deparo com um grande problema, ao digitar o comando:

```
$ ionic cordova build android
```

(Ressalto que fiz os passos corretamente já adicionei a plataforma e tudo já está instalado).

Porém, ele não funciona e me retorna o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar? mas, eu **não quero fazer upgrade** para o ionic 4

Comment: Consegui, fazendo uma gambiarra! programei meu aplicativo na versão ionic 3, quando terminei atualizei o ionic e só gerei o apk... Deu certo, mas caso alguém saiba solucionar o problema ficarei grato.

Comment: Olá. Eu aconselho sempre deixar tudo atualizado, mas iniciar o projeto assim: ionic start myApp super --type=ionic-angular. Dessa maneira vc não precisa dar downgrade em nada, vc só altera o --type.

Comment: Pode ser que algum plugin não foi atualizado quando você fez o downgrade, tenta esse site para atualizar os plugins; https://update.ionic.zone/.

Answer (score 1):

Mantenha sempre a versão do seu ionic atualizada, para acompanhar as atualizações e upgrades.

Para criar um projeto na versão 3 não e necessário dar downgrade na sua versão do ionic, basta executar o seguinte comando:

```
ionic start myapp blank --type=ionic-angular
```

com essa flag ele ira criar um projeto na versão 3 do ionic.
Abraços.